# ASAM MDF library for C#

Tags: c#, winforms, measurement, mdf, asammdf

I have developed an application in which the user can import a csv file of measurement data and see all signals of the measurement in a list and plot them.

I want to enable the user to import .mf4 (ASAM MDF) files as well, but I was not able to find a library for C# to include in my windows forms (in visual studio 2019).

Is there a library for this or do I have to develop it myself?

Comment: does not support .NET

Comment: you mean there is no such a library , and I have to develop myself a method to read these files?

Comment: yes, the publisher who actually developed it should.